# How does the plort market work?

Tags: slime-rancher

In slime rancher, it says that plort values change. My question is, how often to they change, and by how much does their value change?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen, *plort value increases* on the market when you don't sell that kind of plort. For example you sell 10 pink plort, the next day the pink *plort value decreases*, while some *plorts increase or stay neutral*. Or if you don't sell any plorts for **(x amount)** of days, the *plort value increases*, and for **(x amount)** of days the *plorts value could peak its top value*, and that is when you can *sell your plorts for the best value*.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, the change is completely random. It doesn't seem related to how many plorts of a specific type you sell, the value just might go up or down every day at midnight.

Each plort seems to have a maximum and minimum value, as even when an expensive plort's value has been going down for several days in a row, it never seems to reach the levels of early plorts like Pink, Rock, and Tabby.

Comment: I'm not sure it's completely random, at least not at this point. Selling a bunch of a given plort seems to lead to a lowered price the next day.

Comment: Before I discovered some of the late-game slimes, their plorts were all worth around 100+ each. Once I found them and started selling the plorts, the value seemed to drop fairly quickly over the next few days, and now I rarely see them much higher than 50. There has to be some connection to selling them and the price changing.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Sounds more like a one-time thing to make players explore.

Answer (score -2):

I have heard that when far far away from a slime, their plort type goes up in price (good money). When a slime is on your farm, their plort type goes down in price, but after they've been on the farm for 10 days the price goes up again.

Comment: A source for this claim would make this answer much better.